# How to count number of vowel - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, count, procedure

I want to write a procedure like count number of vowel in a column. So if I need it any time, then I do not need to write the procedure again. I want to use like `find_vowel()`;

Example:

```
Select Column_String 
From Tablo1 
Where Column_ID=1
```

Result: "I Am gonna find it"

Vowel: "I,A,o,a,i,i"

There are 6 vowels in the column (including upper - lower characters).

So how can I find the number of vowels in the columns?

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2014

Thanks

Comment: What about characters with accents? I.e. `é` or `û`? Also, what collation are you in?

Comment: Just can be based on english. or (a,e,ı,i,o,ö,u,ü) doesn't matter I could change if I had a procedure.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace all vowels with blank (to delete them) then subtract the length of the vowel-less string from the original length:

```
select
    len(Column_String)
    - len(
        replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(
            lower(Column_String), 'a', ''), 'e', ''), 'i', ''), 'o', ''), 'u', '')
    ) as vowel_count
from ...
```

---

As a function:

```
create function vowel_count(str nvarchar(1024))
returns int
as begin
    return (
      len(str) -
      len(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(
            lower(str), 'a', ''), 'e', ''), 'i', ''), 'o', ''), 'u', ''));
end;
```

Comment: Hi,

select
    LEN(
        replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(lower('CoUnt SOme woRDS'), 'a', ''), 'e', ''), 'i', ''), 'o', ''), 'u', ''), 'ı', ''), 'ö', ''), 'ü', '')
    ) as vowel_count 
I tried to count vowels of some words. But result is 11. Why is it giving wrong result? 

And after this problem i want to make procedure this sql like count_vowel('CoUnt SOme woRDS');

Comment: @SühaGündüz because you are not following my answer. The expression in your comment returns the number of **non-vowels**. As per my answer, you need to subtract that from the length of the original string. ie `select len(col) - len(replace(replace(...)))`

Comment: Yes You are right. Thanks for that.
But how i'm gonna do that a procedure for one word. 

  select
    LEN('cOngratUlAtions') - LEN(
        replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(lower('cOngratUlAtions'), 'a', ''), 'e', ''), 'i', ''), 'o', ''), 'u', ''), 'ı', ''), 'ö', ''), 'ü', '')
    ) as vowel_count 
so I wanna give a word in procedure like variable. 

Exp: findvowel('cOngratUlAtions');
Result: 6

Comment: @SühaGündüz see edit to answer showing how to code as a function

Comment: I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio and your syntax didn't work. I tried to like this

create PROC vowel_count 
@number nvarchar(1024)
as 
begin
  len(@number) - len(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(
            lower(@number), 'a', ''), 'e', ''), 'i', ''), 'o', ''), 'u', ''))
end

and execute " Exec vowel_count @number='DENEME' " but doesn't work why any idea?

Answer (score 2):

One method would be to use the function [`NGrams8k`](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/142316/) to split the string out, and then count the vowels.

This creates a very simple function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION CountVowels (@InputString varchar(8000) )
RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN

    SELECT COUNT(1) AS Vowels
    FROM dbo.NGrams8k(@InputString,1) N
    WHERE N.token IN ('A','a','E','e','I','i','O','o','U','u');

GO
```

Which can then be called using:

```
SELECT YT.Columns, CV.Vowels
FROM YourTable YT
     CROSS APPLY CountVowels(YT.YourColumn) CV;
```

*Note, both of these functions accept a `varchar(8000)` (or you can create an equivilent `nvarchar(4000)`. Performance will be significantly lower if you change the parameters to a `varchar(MAX)` or `nvarchar(MAX)`.*

Answer (score 0):

Pretty easy if you have tally table; the example below shows you how to create a temporary one for the sake of the code.  Note that the example below is based on a case-insensitive collation; as indicated by Larnu's response above, that may need to be addressed.

You can wrap the code in a function or a proc as needed, but I'd suggest that you find a way to do this sort of string manipulation at the application level if possible.  SQL Server is getting better at handling these sorts of things, but it can still be an expensive operation.

```
/*Create tally table; this portion is not necessary if you have one*/
SELECT N= ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY c.name)
INTO #Tally
        FROM sys.columns c



DECLARE @str varchar(8000) = 'I Am gonna find it'

SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM #Tally N
WHERE N <= LEN(@str) AND SUBSTRING(@str,N,1) IN ('A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U')

/*clean up temp tally table*/
DROP TABLE #Tally
```